# Adding object type as a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, django

I need to add an object as value in a dict,

So dict looks like

```
 dict1={"key":"value,"other":"other"}
```

Then I need the newly created Model object as instance to be used later in the code, so

```
 instance = MyModel.objects.create(name="name",someother="some")
```

I need to update the dict to add the instance

```
 dict1['request'] = instance // it will throw an error
 other_def.delay(dict1) // use the contents of dict in celery function
 `exception Object of type MyModel is not JSON serializable`
```

Because I have another model that have relation to MyModel as many-to one

other_def.py

```
 instance = args['instance']
 ChildModel.objects.create(parentinstance=instance,....)
```

I can't use the `instance.id` since it will return an error `must be an instance`

```
  dict1['request']=instance.id //not working
  `Cannot assign "5"...must be a MyModel instance
```

How do you add an instance to a dict?

Regards

Comment: That shouldn't happen when you assign to a dictionary element. It might happen if you later try to do `json.dump(dict1)`.

Comment: Are you sure `dict1` is really a dictionary? Dictionaries don't do any checks like this when you assign to their elements.

Comment: @Barmar, Im pretty sure its a dictionary.Printing type(dict1) yields `<class 'dict'>`

Comment: Then I don't see how this could be happening. Please post a [mre].

Comment: If you want to dump the dictionary to a file keeping the data types, have a look at `pickle`. Anyway, an example would be great as Barmar has mentioned.